# MySQL - Views Alternative

Tags: mysql

I've developed an application at working using MySQL 5, that uses Views to access the major pieces of data.  It turns out that our production server uses MySQL 4, which does not have Views included.

Does anybody have a quick and dirty way to deal with this that doesn't involve rewriting all my code?

Comment: Upgrade the production server? :)

Comment: Man, I knew MySQL was a toy, but I had no idea...

Comment: @Paul: MySQL 5.0 was released over three years ago, with support for views, triggers, and stored procs.  Older versions of any software can be considered weak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This certainly points out the importance of using the same technology in your development and production environments!

Workarounds involving triggers or stored procedures won't work, because these are also not supported on MySQL 4.x.

Your options at this point:

- Rewrite application code to duplicate data in denormalized tables, designed to match your views.
- Upgrade your production database to MySQL 5.0.  If you're talking about a hosting provider, then contact that provider and ask if they have an option for MySQL 5.0, otherwise you need to relocate to a provider who does.

I'd recommend the latter path, it'll be far less work than writing code to manage duplicate data.

Note that MySQL 4.1 was released as production software over four years ago. Active support for this release ended in 2006.  Extended support for MySQL 4.1 ends 2009-12-31.  See http://www.mysql.com/about/legal/lifecycle/

Comment: Thanks

This is, sadly enough, my employer.  They have different environments on production & development servers, and don't even bother to tell one of their programmers.  Upgrading is not an option.  I wonder what the Joel test would say about this??

Comment: Unless they *lied* to you about the production server, I'd say it's 50% your fault for not asking what the production server is running before investing a lot of time using version-specific features.

Comment: @Bill - Lied is a strong word.  The senior developer didn't actually check when I asked about the version on the live server - he just assured me if it worked in the dev environment, it would be fine.

Answer (score 2):

The quick and very dirty way that comes to mind is to subclass DBI and re-write the SQL there. Depends on what you're using views for, of course, and if you mean MySQL 4.0 (does not have subqueries) or MySQL 4.1 (does have subqueries).

If you're on 4.1, you can turn:

```
CREATE VIEW foo AS
  SELECT a, b, c FROM real_table WHERE fooable = 1;

SELECT * FROM foo;
```

into

```
SELECT v1.* FROM (
  SELECT a, b, c FROM real_table WHERE fooable = 1
) v1;
```

At least, the latter syntax works in 5.0.x, I think it should in 4.1.x as well.

If you're on 4.0... well, it won't be as easy.

Comment: You can also change column names using column aliases in the outer query.  Anyway, this would work for 4.1 as you say, but I'm not sure it's especially quick.  :-(

Comment: Yeah, it may not be that quick. That's certainly something to test.

Answer (score 1):

Ouch.  Aside from a DeLorean and a flux capacitor or upgrading the server I don't know of any easy way to get around this issue.  A lot of change seems necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, without upgrading to MySQL 5, probably not.